# What function should I use to open file in mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, c++builder, firemonkey

I use C++ Builder to create my cross-platform application.
In the app, I will get file name/path by open file dialog.
In Windows, it's no problem to take care the unicode string. (ex. "C:\測試")
In mac OS X, I can get correct string from UnicodeString. But I can't find a good method to convert it to char array and use "fopen" to open the file correctly.
I tried to assign the UnicodeString to AnsiString directly but it became "C:\??".
Because "fopen" only accepts "char*" and UnicodeString can only export "char16*", I need to convert it to char for "fopen".
Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_wfopen equivalent under Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319/wfopen-equivalent-under-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because `fopen()` takes a `char*` does not mean you should give it an ANSI string.  POSIX APIs on OSX accept UTF-8 encoded filenames, so use `UTF8String` instead of `AnsiString`.  A `char*` can point to a UTF-8 string.

Otherwise, don't use `fopen()` directly.  Use the RTL's own functions instead, like `FileCreate()`/`FileOpen()` in `System.SysUtils.hpp` unit, or the `TFileStream` class in `System.Classes.hpp` unit.  Let the RTL decide internally how to interact with platform APIs for you.